# Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18470 and 18456 Occurring Simulaneously

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to connect to SQL Server but it seems impossible to do so as both Windows authentication and SQL server authentication are giving error as described in the screenshot posted below:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\harshitsaini15@gmail.com'. Reason: The account is disabled.

[image: Error Image]

[Sql Server Management Startup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Kpp.png)

Most of the resolutions solve either solve any one of the error but none of them give insights on how to resolve the issue if both accounts are locked down. Even the same error occurred while upgrading from version 2016 to 2017.

Comment: I face the same issue. Could you tell me how did you solve this?